# Regression across matrices in list

Tags: r, list, matrix, regression

I want to perform regressions across matrices in a list, and in each case use the last 48 months of data.

Setup

```
Mat1 <- matrix(nrow=310, ncol =48, data= rnorm(310*48, 0, 0.1))
Mat2 <- matrix(nrow =310, ncol= 51, data = rnorm(310*51,0,0.1))
Mat1[1:300, 48] <- NA
Mat2[1:40, 51] <- NA

ind1 <- matrix(nrow =48, ncol =3, data = rnorm(48*3, 0,0.1))
ind2 <- matrix(nrow =51, ncol =3, data = rnorm(51*3, 0,0.1))

list1 <- c(Mat1, Mat2)
ind.list <- c(ind1,ind2)
```

I want to regress rows in List1[i], against columns in ind1[i] using the most recent 48 months of data. For instance, the first regression will regress row 1 of Mat1, against column1 of Ind1, Column2 of Ind1 and Column3 of Ind1. The second regression, will regress row 2 of Mat1, against column1 of Ind1, Column2 of Ind1 and Column3 of Ind1. Repeat this process for all rows in Mat1 and store coefficients.

However, I only want the regression to run if i have data in the last column of each row of Mat1. So to be clear: step1. check if data is present in column 48 row 1 of Mat1. If yes, run regression over 48 months of data. if No store NA in coefficient matrix. Step 2. Is NA present in row2 of Mat1 in column 48? If No, then run regression. If yes, store an NA in coefficient matrix.

Then move to Mat2. Regress  Mat2[1, 3:51] against column 1 of Ind2[3:51,1] column2 of Ind2 i.e Ind2[3:51,2] and column3 of Ind2 i.e Ind2[3:51,3]

Repeat the process for all rows in Mat2 and store beta coefficients in a matrix.

Overall, regress rows of matrices in list1 against the corresponding columns of matrices in Ind1.

What i've tried:

```
for (i in 1:2) {
  for (j in 1:310) {
    coefficients1 = matrix(nrow = 310, ncol = 2)
    coefficients2 = matrix(nrow=310, ncol =2)
    coefficients3 = matrix(nrow=310, ncol =2)
    if(is.na(list1[[i]][j,ncol(is.na(list1[[i]]))])) next
    coefficients1[j,i] = coefficients(lm(list1[[i]][j, ]) ~ ind.list[[i]][,1] + ind.list[[i]][,2] +ind.list[[i]][,3])[1]
    coefficients2[j,i] = coefficients(lm(list1[[i]][j, ]) ~ ind.list[[i]][,1] + ind.list[[i]][,2] +ind.list[[i]][,3])[2]
    cefficients3[j,i] = coefficients(lm(list1[[i]][j, ]) ~ ind1.list[[i]][,1] + ind.list[[i]][,2] +ind.list[[i]][,3])[3]
  }
}
```

Output should stall all the beta coefficients for each corresponding regression. Regression of Mat1 against Ind1 should yield 310 coefficients of Beta1 stored in coefficients1, 310 coefficients of beta2, stored in coefficients2 and 310 coefficients of beta3, stored in coefficients3.

Comment: You are re-initializing your coefficients matrices every time through the looping. Wrong. Put them outside the loops.

Comment: @42- i still get the error: Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `apply` which works well on matrices.

```
total_mat1 <- t(apply(Mat1, 1, function(x) coefficients(lm(x~ind1))))

#Change the values to NA when the last value of Mat1 is NA
total_mat1[is.na(Mat1[, ncol(Mat1)]), ] <- NA
```

`total_mat1` is a matrix of 310 rows X 4 columns.

Now similar for `Mat2` after subsetting selected rows and columns.

```
total_mat2 <- t(apply(Mat2[, 3:51], 1, function(x) coefficients(lm(x~ind2[3:51,]))))
```

---

To first check the `NA` values and then perform the analysis we can do

```
total_mat1 <- matrix(NA, nrow = nrow(Mat1), ncol = 4)
inds <- !is.na(Mat1[, ncol(Mat1)])
total_mat1[inds, ] <- t(apply(Mat1[inds, ],1, function(x) coefficients(lm(x~ind1))))
```

Comment: I get the following error when i try to apply this on my actual sample.  Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 0 (non-NA) cases 

This is likely because my Mat1 and Mat2 in actual cases are full of NAs in some cases. Is there a way to do this in a functional form that first checks whether NA's are present and then perform the regression?